# pass variables to php with ajax load()

Tags: ajax, variables, load

I found some close answers for this, but none of them worked in my case. I have:

1. Input tag:

   ```
     <input name="title" id="title">
   ```
2. Ajax:

   ```
   <script language="javascript">
   function example_ajax_request() {

       $('#example-placeholder').html('<p><img src="/img/ajax-loader.gif" /></p>');

       setTimeout('example_ajax_request_go()', 0);

   }

   function example_ajax_request_go() {

       $j(document).ready(function () {

           var inputField = $j('#inputText').val();

           $j(".button").click(function () {

               $('#example-placeholder').load('preview.php?title=' + title + ' .aClass');

           }
      </script>
   ```
3. Button to call the function:

   ```
   <input type="button" onclick="example_ajax_request()" value="Preview" />
   ```

I'm trying to pass 'title' var from the input tag via ajax to 'preview.php'. This code above has errors and is not running, can you suggest correct one? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have not put in exact error messages (from your browser's console, please put them in and update your question). I am just putting across some suggestions/improvements:

1. Whenever you are passing GET parameters, always URIEncode the value(the `xyz` and `value` in `url?abc=xyz&blah=value`). In javascript there is a function call `EncodeURIComponent(..)`. You would use it like:

   ```
   'preview.php?title=' +  EncodeURIComponent(title +' .aClass')
   ```
2. A possible typo, you have have a space in the URL, before the `+ ' .aClass'`. If you need one, explicitly replace it with a `+` or `%20`.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way. Here it is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function example_ajax_request() {
 $('#example-placeholder').html('<p><img src="img/ajax-loader.gif" /></p>');
 $('#example-placeholder').load("preview.php?title="+$('#title').val());
}
</script>
```

Thanks!